# C - Root is not printing the right value, is not changing from sum

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

This is part of a homework assignment in which the user input five ints, and it is put through several functions, getting the sum, average, sqrt, and a couple other things. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// needs to be declared in order to work
int functionPrint(int sum, int root);

//sum function, takes all the ints from main and sums it up
int functionSum(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
    int sum = one + two + three + four + five;
    // sends the sum to the print function
    sum = functionPrint(sum, sum);
}

//sqrt function, will take all numbers and square root them
int functionSqrt(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
    int root = sqrt(three);
    // sends the sqrt numbers to print
    root = functionPrint(root, root);
}

int functionPrint(int sum, int root) {
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf("Square Root: %d\n", root);
}

//main function, all values to be worked are created here and sent to the other functions
int main() {
    int sumMain, one, two, three, four, five;

    printf("Enter five numbers separated by spaces: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &one, &two, &three, &four, &five);

    sumMain = functionSum(one, two, three, four, five);
}
```

Currently, it is supposed to print out only the sum and sqrt of the int three (I'll include the other ints when I get this fixed). `functionPrint()` begins on line 21, and `functionSqrt()` begins at line 15. But, like I said, it only prints the sum. My guess is that there is some variable that exists that must be overwritten, or something like that. But then again I'm no expert.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think perhaps you need to learn about return statements.

Comment: Check that the `scanf()` call returns 5; if not, you've got an input format problem.  You say that it only prints the sum; it should print the same value and label it 'Square Root' (which is a misnomer, but that doesn't matter).  You never call the `functionSqrt()` AFAICS.  It's not a particularly good idea to ignore 4 of the 5 parameters. None of the functions returns a value, even though you say they do.  That's bad, especially since you try to assign the returned values.  The functions should all be declared and defined to return `void` and the return value assignments should be removed.

Comment: You still have not called your functionSqrt function, you are just adding the values in the function named functionSum and then passing the values as call by value to print in the print function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` and change the `scanf` to:

```
int result = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &one, &two, &three, &four, &five);
if (result != 5)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to read five numbers.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This will test for an input problem. It is always good to test for problems and report them early, rather than letting the program go on to fail in strange ways later.

Change `functionSum` to **return** a value. `functionSum` is declared with `int functionSum(…)`, which means it is supposed to return a value. To actually return a value, you need to put a `return` statement in it:

```
int functionSum(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five)
{
    return one + two + three + four + five;
}
```

In the `main` program, call `functionPrint` after `functionSum`:

```
sumMain = functionSum(one, two, three, four, five);
functionPrint(sumMain, 0);
```

That should take care of calculating the sum and printing it. Understanding these changes should help you progress on the square root.

Answer (score -1):

1. In main()

   ```
   scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &one, &two, &three, &four, &five);
   ```

scanf() will not work as you want, there's no specific delimiter in formation string("%d%d%d%d%d"), how would you divide your 5 inputs?

2. In main()

   ```
   sumMain = functionSum(one, two, three, four, five);
   ```

sumMain will not get the sum value you want, because functionSum() do not "return" any value, please google "C language" + "return" by yourself.

3. modified functionSum() and functionSqrt() according your search result in step 2. You may not need functionPrint().

Comment: Your statement about `scanf` is wrong. It will work exactly as intended since each of the `%d` will skip over spaces in the input.

Answer (score -2):

Modification Done to your program as per the required output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// needs to be declared in order to work
int functionPrint(int sum, int root);

//sum function, takes all the ints from main and sums it up
int functionSum(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
    int sum = one + two + three + four + five;
    float sqrt = functionSqrt(one,two,three,four,five);  // Called the Sqrt function and receives the square root of the third number
    // sends the sum to the print function
    sum = functionPrint(sum, sqrt);
}

//sqrt function, will take all numbers and square root them
int functionSqrt(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
    int root = sqrt(three);
    return root;
    // sends the sqrt numbers to print
  //  root = functionPrint(root, root);
}

int functionPrint(int sum, int root) {
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    printf("Square Root: %d\n", root);
}

//main function, all values to be worked are created here and sent to the other functions
int main() {
    int sumMain, one, two, three, four, five;

    printf("Enter five numbers separated by spaces: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", &one, &two, &three, &four, &five);

    sumMain = functionSum(one, two, three, four, five);
}
```

Comment: `functionSum` still not returning anything or make it return void and remove assignments.